# Finding image of reviewed question back again

Tags: image

I searched Stackoverflow for questions about highlighting lines of a text (in HTML with JavaScript). I solved the task. Now I want to make a small presentation. One of the questions, which I found had a good illustation, which I want to use - but I can't find it again (I am trying it since one week now).
The image was similar to the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36036961/highlight-paragraph-line-by-line-on-hover), but was a bit smaller, more brown and of higher quality.

Comment: This question seems off-topic for SO. Have a look at your browser's history to find out what SO pages you've visited, also this meta question might be related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286956/how-to-see-my-visited-question-pages-url-history

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I couldn't find it in my history.